# Asp.Net Core change url in launchSettings.json not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to change the default url ( http://localhost:5000 ) when i run the website as a console application .

I edited launchSettings.json but it doesn't work ... it still uses port 5000 :

```
    {
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:4230/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "website": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost:80",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try changing the url via project properties, rather than editing the launcher.json? I'd guess VS does update the IIS express web.config files with the url when you do it via the UI but doesn't when you run change it in the json

Comment: There are two places where the IISExpress ports are configured. First one is `%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config` in the `applicationhost.config`. The other one is located solution-wide configuration in the `.vs/config` folder, same filename. This ones determine the port number used when IIS Express launches the application

Comment: http://benfoster.io/blog/how-to-configure-kestrel-urls-in-aspnet-core-rc2  check this may help you

Comment: It's incredible that 2 years later this still doesn't work!!!

Comment: You're trying to bind a port < 1024 as a regular user. Maybe it's defaulting to 5000?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the url when you build the  "BuildWebHost". Hope this one helps you https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/639

Below is the code I use in my .net core 2.0 console application

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseUrls("http://localhost:5050/")
            .Build();
        
    
}
```

Screenshot of the console output:
[image]

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution. Please edit to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Answer (score 3):

Using Kestrel you can specify port using hosting.json file.

Add hosting.json with the following content to you project:

```
{
    "server.urls": "http://0.0.0.0:5002" 
}
```

and add to publishOptions in project.json

```
"publishOptions": {
"include": [
  "hosting.json"
  ]
}
```

and in entry point for the application call ".UseConfiguration(config)" when creating WebHostBuilder:

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true)
                .Build();

            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseConfiguration(config)
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
```

Comment: Alternatively, chain on `.UseUrls("http://localhost:5002")` after instantiating the WebHostBuilder

Answer (score 0):

If you want this button working again with the ports you want

[image]

delete `bin/Debug` within your project folder and be happy

Answer (score -2):

I encountered similar problem, changing applicationUrl in launchSettings.json not work .

finally I founded that it is override by this item in `appsettings.json` or `appsettings.Development.json`

```
   "urls": "https://localhost:5101",
```

Comment: This is not really a helpful answer. Please consider the answers in this post with multiple upvotes as well written and good effort answers. They all provide a context and explanation of the solution.

Comment: @Ebbelink i encountered this kind of problem and fixed it. i think it's you who not understand